# First DNS Lookup always fails

Tags: dns, nslookup

I'm having a very weird problem with a new Windows 10 Pro build using an intel I219-v adapter (integrated into the mobo). Every time a DNS lookup occurs, either in a browser or triggered manually via command prompt, the first request times out and then the next resolves properly. I only have the two google servers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) configured as dns servers in the adapter settings and configured on the router (Tried both manual and automatic discovery). From what I can see the wireshark capture looks normal. I've been tearing my hair out all day as it completely ruins the browsing experience on the computer.

Below are some screenshots illustrating the problem:

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFEC0.png)

[nslookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOoF6.png)

wireshark: http:// i.stack.imgur.com/ETpTa.png

Comment: Have you tried with another set of name servers before we start thinking about this too much?

Comment: I experience the same thing on Windows10 home. I've tried OpenDNS servers, reverting back to ISP servers and so on. Every time I get failure on the first attempt and a second later the domain will be resolved.

Comment: this does not look like OS issue. Try these tests:1) launch a virtualbox with linux inside an try from there 2) take your laptop to another place, public wi fi for example and test there 3) disable antivirus/personal firewall and test

Comment: No sufficient answer was provided. My personal experience is that it's about the network configuration. As a personal traveling frequently, I see some networks I connect do present this issue. Perhaps a faulty router or ISP policy or bug. Don't know.

Answer (score 3):

You can try all possible fixes:

- Try disabling malwarebytes/firewall
- Try resetting DNS client
- Try flushing DNS cache
- Remove IPv6 option under particular connection

Sometimes i faced few strange issue,

- Skype was working fine, but, i was not able to browse in browsers due to dns issue.  so it worked when cleared all temp files.
- When i connect with different internet connections, for example, 3G, broadband, that time i faced issues.  For that, i installed one utility to flush DNS in all connections quickly.

Try one by one and see if you can solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about the OSI model.

[image: OSI Model]

Working from the bottom up, it sounds like you have the physical, data link, and network layers in check as demonstrated with the wireshark image. Application *appears* fine. My guess is that something might be happening between Transport-Presentation. As someone said, disabling anti-virus might solve between the presentation and application layers. If connected to a VPN, do you still have the same problem? Do you have more than 1 network adapter? Windows 10 will send DNS requests to all available adapters and it might be incorrectly choosing one.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see how this answer is related to the question. Why would the behavior be different on first and subsequent requests?

Comment: Narrowing out possibilities of where the problem may lay. The OSI model is the first thing you learn about when going for a Cisco certification to narrow down peculiar networking issues like this. Sorry for trying to narrow the scope of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to flush the dnscache:

Open a cmd:

`ipconfig/flushdns`

Comment: On the contrary. If the IP was in the cache there wouldn't have been a DNS lookup which is what fails the first time. As it happens with all websites (including those never visited) and following restarts, it has nothing to do with the cache. Thanks.